# memory diagnostic tool for visual studio 2012 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a form which doesn't free resources when closed. With what tool I can inspect what's happening ?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a built-in profiler in VS2012 (may depend on which version of VS2012). Microsoft also has a free [CLR Profiler for .NET 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16273)

Red Gate makes an excellent [memory profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/), which I find easier to use than the above alternatives, but it isn't free. There is a fully functional free trial that you can use to solve your problem.

Regarding your problem: the usual leak problem with forms are event handlers. Make sure you don't have any event handlers in the form that are coupled to a central class that isn't disposed.

There are also a few annoying bugs in the framework that attach central windows events such as "ui theme changed" to static fields in framework classes. This can for example result in classes hosting a windows forms toolbar never being garbage collected. Event handler leaks are tricky to find, so tricky that they even still exist in the framework code apparently.